# Баг или неверный запрос?

Tags: sql, access

Имеется таблица MovementGoods, в ней поля Date_, Count_.
Первое поле типа даты, второе числовое. Пишу такой запрос:

```
SELECT Sum(MovementGoods.Count_) AS [SumCount]
FROM MovementGoods
GROUP BY [SumCount];
```

Казалось бы проще некуда, а тем не менее, это не работает. 
Идет суммирование числовых значений и групировка по полю SumCount.
В чем проблема?

Comment: А что именно должен сделать ваш запрос. Посчитать сумму MovementGoods.Count_ по всем MovementGoods (получить одно значение для всей таблицы) + сгруппировать по этому одному значению? Что вы ожидаете увидеть в результате?

Comment: @PashaPash, да просто вывести сумму чисел распределенных в определенные даты. Тем не менее, запрос не работает, и требует ввести значение SumCount. Это простейший вариант, где агрегатная функция SUM, в конце запроса указана группировка по этому полю. В чем проблема? Интересно просто такое работает?

Comment: Если вам нужна просто сумма - то не делайте группировку, и сумму посчитает по всей таблице. Если вам нужна сумма по датам - сделайте группировку по полю даты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это неверный запрос. Порядок выполнения операторов `SELECT` таков:

```
FROM 
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
SELECT
ORDER BY
```

Таким образом на момент когда делается `GROUP BY` -- `SumCount` еще не существует. Надо

```
SELECT Sum(MovementGoods.Count_) AS [SumCount]
FROM MovementGoods
GROUP BY какоето поле;
```

Comment: Да, именно это я и хотел знать. Спасибо за порядок работы запроса. Это важно